# Unable to Import JSON data from local file using ES6 import in a React Redux Webpack App

Tags: json, reactjs, webpack, redux

I am trying to learn building a React + Redux application architecture using Web Pack 3 for bundling. I am trying to work with temporary JSON files for data sets and importing them into Service files which want to use the data returned from the imported JSON.

I try to use the imported JSON in Promise.resolve(JSON) and somehow the value seems to be undefined.

**Note**: This block is inside in IIFE block.

Find the service code below.

```
import jsonVal from './josnFile.json';

export default (function() {
    return {
        method1: methodName1,
        method2: methodName2,
        ...
    }

    function methodName1(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            resolve(jsonVal);
            // ...usual then, catch blocks for returning rejects
        });
    }
}());
```

After all this flow, I have set up the reducers and actions to appropriately update the Redux state. But no update happens because the JSON data is always *undefined* and when I try to pass this down to the presentational React components via Redux connect (mapStateToProps), its undefined too.

I want to know what should I do to include this JSON for mocking APIs. 
Whether I have to use a JSON loader in webpack or any other solution?

**Note**: I am using babel-node to transpile ES6 code

Comment: 1. Are you sure the path to json is correct? I see that you're trying to import `./josnFile.json`. There's a typo: "josnFile.json" -> "jsonFile.json" ;)
2. Have you tried with json-loader for webpack? https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader

Comment: on a side note, you don't need an IIFE because everything is scoped to the module

Comment: @jimmyweb - Yes, Path to json is correct, this is just a sample code I used here, and also I have tried using webpack JSON loader. Still same results.